# 3 dimensional array with different sizes of 2d array in each index

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 3 dimensional array where each index contains a 2 dimensional array with different sizes. So basically it's an array of 2d arrays.
I have these arrays:

```
boolean [][] alpha = new boolean [5][3];
boolean [][] beta = new boolean [10][5];
boolean [][][] all = new boolean [5][][];
```

I tried this but obviously it was wrong :

```
all [0][][] = alpha;
all [1][][] = beta;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
all [0] = alpha;
all [1] = beta;
```